# PHP: while or foreach. I want to save an array of input data which also uses a counter

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to achieve the following

I have post data which is  an array[]

I'm using a foreach to run through the array

```
foreach($images as $image){

  update_option( 'image-'. $mycounter .'', $image );

}
```

I need $mycounter to be counting as it runs through the  foreach. How can I achieve that. I tried it with a while loop but not working  :(

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [incrementing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):

```
$mycounter = 0;

foreach($images as $image){

  update_option( 'image-'. $mycounter .'', $image );
  $mycounter++; // increments through each iteration

}
```

**OR** use the unique numerical indices as your counter, *assuming* the indices are numerical.

```
foreach($images as $index => $image){

  update_option( 'image-'. $index .'', $image );

}
```

Comment: +1 Never thought of using the index; I've always used `for()` loops or counter variables. Great idea, thanks! Edit: This will only work for numeric keys, obviously. Be careful of that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mycounter = 0;
foreach($images as $image){

  update_option( 'image-'. $mycounter .'', $image );
  $mycounter++;
}
```

Like that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried incrementing `$mycounter` every iteration?

```
$mycounter = 0;

foreach($images as $image)
{
    update_option('image-' . $mycounter, $image);
    $mycounter++;
}
```

Or am I misunderstanding the question?